Selecting rows in pandas dataframe that contain same id and were created within 1 minute
I have a pandas dataframe that contains multiple rows with one identificator and the datetime of the row.



id
creation_date




MP5694319-001
2024-05-29 12:58:00.489


MP5694319-001
2024-05-29 12:58:03.489


MP5694331-001
2024-05-29 12:58:05.489


MP5694319-001
2024-05-29 13:03:03.489



From this dataframe I need to filter rows that contain both the same id and were created within 1 minute from each other. The final result:



id
creation_date




MP5694319-001
2024-05-29 12:58:00.489


MP5694319-001
2024-05-29 12:58:03.489



Dataframe contains multiple rows with various id, so I need to group them somehow and then apply the difference, but I have no idea how to do this.

You can use DataFrame.sort_values forst, get difference per groups in both directions by DataFrameGroupBy.diff and filter by Series.le for less or equal in boolean indexing:
df['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date'])

df = df.sort_values(['id','creation_date'])

g = df.groupby('id')['creation_date']
out = df[g.diff().le('1 min') | g.diff(-1).abs().le('1 min')]
print (out)
              id           creation_date
0  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489
1  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:03.489

Another idea is back filling first value of difference per groups for include in output:
df['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date'])

df = df.sort_values(['id','creation_date'])

g = df.groupby('id')['creation_date']
out = df[g.transform(lambda x: x.diff().bfill()).le('1 min')]
print (out)
              id           creation_date
0  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489
1  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:03.489


Thank you, it actually works, but it also filters out some of the rows that must be in the final result. E.g.: first row MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489, second row MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.512. Doth rows don't appear in the final result. Maybe it is affected by the sorting order of the dataframe?

Using your method we are only analyzing the rows that are GREATER than the previous row? How can we look on both sides and filter rows that are lesser or greater by 1 minute?

@Alice - Excatly, you need sorting first - df = df.sort_values(['id','creation_date'])

@Alice - I use le('1 min') for less or equal 1 minute, if need greater need gt instead le, if need greater or equal need ge

You can typically use a self-merge_asof with tolerance:
# data must be sorted by timestamp
df['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['creation_date', 'id'])

out = (pd.merge_asof(df,
                     df[['id', 'creation_date']].assign(flag=True),
                     by='id', on='creation_date',
                     direction='nearest',
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1min'),
                     allow_exact_matches=False)
         .loc[lambda x: x.pop('flag').eq(True)]
      )

Output:
              id           creation_date
0  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489
1  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:03.489

If you want to identify which value was identified as pair, rename the column, then dropna:
out = (pd.merge_asof(df,
                     df[['id', 'creation_date']]
                     .rename(columns={'creation_date':
                                      'creation_date_2'}),
                     by='id', left_on='creation_date',
                     right_on='creation_date_2',
                     direction='nearest',
                     tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1min'),
                     allow_exact_matches=False)
         .dropna(subset=['creation_date_2'])
      )

Output:
              id           creation_date         creation_date_2
0  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489 2024-05-29 12:58:03.489
1  MP5694319-001 2024-05-29 12:58:03.489 2024-05-29 12:58:00.489


By using this method I get the error "ValueError: left keys must be sorted". Do you have an idea of how it can be fixed?

With df = df.sort_values(by=['creation_date', 'id']), the keys should be sorted. Have you run this step?

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': ['MP5694319-001', 'MP5694319-001', 'MP5694331-001', 'MP5694319-001'],
    'date': [
        '1990-05-29 12:58:00.489',
        '1990-05-29 12:58:03.489',
        '1990-05-29 12:58:05.489',
        '1990-05-29 13:03:03.489'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'])
'''
First Expression (diff() without -1): Looks backward in time.
 It checks if the current row is close (within 1 minute) to the row before it.

Second Expression (diff(-1)): Looks forward in time. 
It checks if the current row is close (within 1 minute) to the row after it.
'''
# Step 2: Use shift to calculate time differences
df['prev_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.total_seconds()   <= 60
df['next_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff(-1).dt.total_seconds() <= 60
 
# Step 3: Filter rows where the time difference is <= 60 seconds
#result = df[(df['prev_diff'] <= 60) | (df['next_diff'] <= 60)]
result = df[(df['prev_diff'] ) | (df['next_diff'] )]

#result = result.drop(columns=['prev_diff', 'next_diff'])

print(result)
'''
              id                    date  prev_diff  next_diff
0  MP5694319-001 1990-05-29 12:58:00.489      False       True
1  MP5694319-001 1990-05-29 12:58:03.489       True       True
'''

